# Where to find region code on linkedin web scraping

Tags: java, html, web, linkedin-api

I was using Python to web-scrape some profiles on LinkedIn for academic research. Based on searching results, I noticed that LinkedIn has regional codes:

E.g., 106474520 is for Santa Barbara, 106474520 for Los Angeles, and 103925994 for Tokyo

Does anyone know where to find a code book for this type of LinkedIn region code?

Comment: Have you tried contacting LinkedIn?

Comment: No. I didn't. I don't know which department I should contact and the phone number....

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a518597/contact-linkedin-customer-service?lang=en

Comment: The link above is for LinkedIn customer service. They should be able to put you in contact with technical support. I was going to send you the LinkedIn API link, but unless you know where to go, it's kind of hard to navigate. I think your best bet is to have them put you in contact with technical support or some internal dev team.

Comment: Also, you might not need to web-scrape at all if they have an API that could provide the information you need.